# Fortran 90 intent(in) for a recursive function

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Does the following code conform to the Fortran 90 standard?

```
integer, pointer :: pa ! global
...

recursive subroutine foo(a)
integer, target, intent(in) :: a

  if (a > 10) then
    return
  endif

  if (associated(pa)) then
    pa = 123
  endif
  pa => a

  call foo(a + 1)

  ! use a

end subroutine foo
```

Variable `a` is declared with intent(in), which according to the [Fortran 90 standard](https://wg5-fortran.org/N001-N1100/N692.pdf), section 5.1.2.3:

> specifies  that  the  dummy  argument  must  not  be  redefined  or  become  undefined during the execution of the procedure

Variable `a` does not get redefined at the level of recursion of `foo(a)`; instead, we save a pointer to `a` so we can redefine `a` on a lower level of recursion.

In other words:

```
foo(a) ! do not change a, save the pointer to a
  foo(a + 1) ! change a, save the pointer to a + 1
    foo(a + 1 + 1) ! change a + 1, save the pointer to a + 1 + 1, and so on.
```

Based on my understanding of the standard, the lifetime of `foo(a + 1)` is a subset of the lifetime of `foo(a)`, so `a` should not be changed.
Is it safe for the compiler to assume that `foo()` has "undefined behaviour" (or Fortran's equivalent of it)?

Comment: To add a little to IanH's answer: the subroutine `foo` _is_ conforming.  However, a main program using it may not be (for the reasons mentioned in that answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the value of the actual argument that gets associated with `a` that the procedure is initially called with, and the association status of `pa` prior to the first call.

If `a` is greater than 10, the code is conforming (and not very exciting).

If `a` is equal to 10, and the pointer association status of `pa` is undefined, the code is non-conforming.  The `associated` intrinsic requires its actual argument to be defined.  If `a` is equal to 10 and the pointer association status of `pa` is not undefined, the code is conforming.

If `a` is less than 10, the code is non-conforming.  The INTENT(IN) dummy argument `a` of the first instance of execution of the procedure is redefined via assignment to the pointer `pa` during nested execution of the next instance.  The rules around INTENT(IN) require that the value of non-pointer dummy arguments not be changed during invocation or execution of the procedure, directly or indirectly.

Beyond diagnostics not relevant here, a conforming Fortran processor can do whatever it wants when executing unconforming code, but conformance versus non-conformance here is an execution time question.

Many corrections to the Fortran 90 standard have been effectively issued over the years, perhaps most of which have been made via edits to subsequent standards.  Words in later standards are slightly different, but requirements in this area haven't changed.